# Fullcalendar rending inside of a tab (not ui tabs)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have fullcalendar placed inside a tab based on the [jqwidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/#demos/jqxtabs/defaultfunctionality.htm).

When I click on the selected tab, the top row of buttons shows up but not the calendar itself. The calendar does show once you click on one of the top row buttons.

I have read the other posts here on how to do this with the standard ui.tabs component, and tried it, but it doesn't work. Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var theme = '';
        // Create jqxTabs.
        jQuery('#classInfo').jqxTabs({ 
            width: "100%", 
            height: "1000px", 
            autoHeight: false, 
            position: 'top', 
            theme: theme, 
            show: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery('#classcalendar').fullCalendar('render');
                }
        });
        jQuery('#settings div').css('margin-top', '10px');
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default FullCalendar doesn't render inside hidden elements. And the show event binder **doesn't** apply to jqxTabs. It only applies to jQuery UI tabs.

Try the selected event binder instead:

```
$('#classInfo').bind('selected', function (event) { 
  if(event.args.item=="3") {
    jQuery('#classcalendar').fullCalendar('render');
  }
});
```

Here `3` is the index of the tab which holds the calendar. You can put any condition which applies to your case here.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying this but it's still not working.  I have loaded a sample showing the problem in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/robbrandt/dBzby/

You can see the problem best by showing the results in a full page:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/robbrandt/dBzby/show/

Comment: Check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/AQBAC/
This should work correctly now. The `event.args.item` actually returns the index of the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try this will work

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == "#tab_Calendar1") {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar()...;
    } else if ($(e.target).attr('href') == "#tab_Calendar2") {
        $('#calendar1').fullCalendar()....;
    }
});
$('#calendarTab a:first').tab('show');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a container within the hidden the tab:

```
<div id='calendar-container'></div>
```

Then put the calendar init HTML somewhere that is visible like out side of the tabs.

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

The calendar will render outside of the tabs with the standard fullCalendar() JS.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar();
```

The next step is to move the calendar to the hidden tab within our container with a jQuery .appendTo() function. Here is the JS all put together. Hope that helps.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar().appendTo("#calendar-container");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
})
```